# Jenkinsfile / recordIssues create "filter" Array from file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We are using `recordIssues` from the "Warnings Next Generation Plugin" to Visualise Results that have been generated by the Trivy-Dockerimage-Scanner "aquasec/trivy". This tool can scan docker images against several CVE Databases.

The results are generated with

```
        recordIssues(enabledForFailure: true,
          aggregatingResults: true,
          qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL_ERROR', unstable: true]],
          filters: [
            excludeType('CVE-2017-15095'),
            excludeType('CVE-2017-17485'),
          ],
          tools: [issues(pattern: '*-issues.json', reportEncoding: 'UTF-8')])
```

I have approx. 180 CVEs that can be ignored as they are not affecting our Software. I would like to generate the array dynamically from a external file instead of adding 180 times `excludeType('CVE-2017-17485'),`and so on ...

**Update**

Based on Matts kind answer the script looks like this now :

```
  stages {
    stage("Scan") {
      steps {
        sh """#!/bin/bash 
           echo "do some stuff"
        """
        script {
          List<String> cve = readYaml file: 'ignored_cves.yaml'
        }
        recordIssues(enabledForFailure: true,
          aggregatingResults: true,
          qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL_ERROR', unstable: true]],
          filters: cve.collect {excludeType(it)},
          tools: [issues(pattern: '*-issues.json', reportEncoding: 'UTF-8')])
     }
    }
  }
```

But when running in Jenkins I receive :

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: cve for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
```

I am wondering how to access `cve` Groovy Object inside `recordIssue`. Possibly I have to do this inside a Jenkins Library.

Comment: have you found the solution to handle this usecase?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We do extent the list every time a new CVE has to be added

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your `cve` variable only exists within the `script { ... }`

Either bring it out:

```
List<String> cve = null // <--- out of script { ... } block

pipeline {
  ...
  stages {
    stage("Scan") {
      steps {
        ...
        script {
          cve = readYaml file: 'ignored_cves.yaml'
        }
        recordIssues(...,
          ...,
          ...,
          filters: cve.collect {excludeType(it)},
          ...)
     }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

...or move `recordIssues` into the `script { ... }` block:

```
  stages {
    stage("Scan") {
      steps {
        ...
        script {
          List<String> cve = readYaml file: 'ignored_cves.yaml'
          recordIssues(... // <--- within script { ... } block
            ...
            ...
            filters: cve.collect {excludeType(it)},
            ...)
        }
     }
    }
  }
```